# getting bad view when coloring button in android

Tags: android, background-color

i've created an android application which creates 50 button dynamically,which works perfectly, but the problem is i'm getting bad view when i put some background color for these buttons dynamically using code given below

```
buttons[i][j].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
buttons[i][j].setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
```

my code is as given below, can anyone please tell me some solution for this

my **Android Platform is 2.3.3**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MyMain extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mymain);
        createCalender();
    }
    public void createCalender()
    {  
        LinearLayout layoutVertical = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.liVLayout);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);
        LinearLayout rowLayout=null;
        Button[][] buttons = new Button[10][5]; 
        int count=51;
        int tab=1;
        for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) 
        {
            if(count%5==1)
            {
                rowLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
                rowLayout.setWeightSum(5);
                layoutVertical.addView(rowLayout,param);
                count=count-5;
            }
            for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
            {
                buttons[i][j]=new Button(this);
                buttons[i][j].setText(""+tab);
                buttons[i][j].setHeight(35);
                buttons[i][j].setWidth(75);                                            
                buttons[i][j].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                buttons[i][j].setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                tab++;

                rowLayout.addView(buttons[i][j],param);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: are you sure about this `buttons[i[j].setWidth(75);` ?

Comment: sorry that is a mistake at edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add some margin to leave these buttons some breathing room.

```
// First try with WRAP_CONTENT
LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramForButtons = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);

// If the buttons look too small using WRAP_CONTENT, change to MATCH_PARENT
// Set the margins in this case
LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramForButtons = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);


paramForButtons.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
```

Replace the last line of your `for` loop with:

```
rowLayout.addView(buttons[i][j],paramForButtons);
```

Comment: @user2018186 No problem. I have another suggestion for you. After you call `rowLayout = new LinearLayout(this);`, set rowLayout's background color to some color other than green: rowLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK). This should make the buttons stand out.

Comment: superbb........sir when we clicking those buttons it does'nt shows any effects not action, like that we can see in normal buttons when we click it will eject inside ..... how can we do that here.....

Comment: @user2018186 Would you like to start another question? Its hard to answer in comments. But I can help you with that effect.

Comment: sir i've posted a new question for that [making press effect for button in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769264/making-press-effect-for-button-in-android)