# making press effect for button in android

Tags: android, button

i've created an android application which creates 50 button dynamically,which works perfectly, but the problem is when i put some background color for these buttons dynamically the press effect of the buttons is being lost

can anyone please tell me some solution for retaining the press effect of the button click
my code is as given below
my **Android Platform is 2.3.3**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MyMain extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mymain);
        createCalender();
    }
   public void createCalender()
   {  
    LinearLayout layoutVertical = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.liVLayout);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);


    param.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);


    LinearLayout rowLayout=null;
    Button[][] buttons = new Button[10][5]; 
    int count=51;
    int tab=1;
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) 
    {
        if(count%5==1)
        {
            rowLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
            rowLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            rowLayout.setWeightSum(5);
            layoutVertical.addView(rowLayout,param);
            count=count-5;
        }
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            buttons[i][j]=new Button(this);
            buttons[i][j].setText(""+tab);
            buttons[i][j].setHeight(55);
            buttons[i][j].setWidth(80);
            buttons[i][j].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            buttons[i][j].setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

            tab++;

            rowLayout.addView(buttons[i][j],param);

        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `buttons[i][j].setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);`

```
buttons[i][j].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY); // Choose whichever color

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

                // Button Click Code Here
            }

        }, 100L);    // Change this value to whatever is suitable

    }

});
```